# LinuxMint15: Suspend to RAM not working

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-mint, suspend

I just installed LinuxMint15 on an Acer Aspire V3-771G-73638G500Maii.

Hibernation works. But suspend to RAM does not.

When clicking suspend: After a few seconds the screen goes grey and then off. The network is turned off. The computer's fan stops spinning. The power LED is slowly blinking orange. The battery led still on. All in all this is what I would expect.

When clicking the power button the fan turns on. The power LED goes blue. Harddisk LED blinks a few times. Up to here it looks like what I would expect. But then: Screen remains off. Network remains down. A running "cat" started before suspending does not continue running (i.e. the harddisk LED does not start blinking hectically).

Clicking the power button again does nothing. Power off is needed. Ctrl-Alt-SysRq-REISUB does not boot the system.

This leads me to believe that this is not just an issue re-activating the graphics card, but that the system is not running.

The system has full disk encryption, so this problem could be that the system is selecting the wrong graphics card (showing nothing on the screen) and awaiting passphrase, but entering the passphrase in the blind does nothing (i.e. the running "cat" does not continue).

What is going on? How can I fix it, so that suspend to ram (and restore) actually works?

---

System info:

Linux mint15 3.8.0-25-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:47:07 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Two graphics cards (lshw):

```
            description: VGA compatible controller
            product: GK107M [GeForce GT 740M]
            vendor: NVIDIA Corporation

         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
```

I am pretty sure it only uses the Intel card (nothing in syslog or Xorg.0.log says anything about nv, nvidia, nouveau). I added this to /etc/default/grub to make restoring graphics from hibernation work:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

The system has full disk encryption.

pm-suspend.log:

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Sat Oct 12 11:10:07 CEST 2013: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux aspire 3.8.0-25-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 6 20:47:07 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
autofs4                36475  1 
rfcomm                 42641  16 
bnep                   18036  2 
parport_pc             28152  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
binfmt_misc            17500  1 
nfsd                  248016  2 
auth_rpcgss            40632  1 nfsd
nfs_acl                12837  1 nfsd
nfs                   164047  0 
lockd                  76670  2 nfs,nfsd
sunrpc                235585  6 nfs,nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
fscache                57430  1 nfs
ext2                   72837  1 
uvcvideo               80847  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13056  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13202  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40513  1 uvcvideo
videodev              129260  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
coretemp               13355  0 
kvm_intel             132891  0 
kvm                   443165  1 kvm_intel
joydev                 17377  0 
arc4                   12615  2 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36913  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    78399  1 
ath9k                 149924  0 
ath9k_common           14055  1 ath9k
snd_hda_intel          39619  3 
ath9k_hw              413680  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_hda_codec         136453  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
ath                    23827  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
snd_pcm                97451  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
mac80211              606457  1 ath9k
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30180  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61554  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              510937  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
ath3k                  12918  0 
acer_wmi               32467  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 acer_wmi
mac_hid                13205  0 
snd                    68876  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
btusb                  22474  0 
psmouse                95870  0 
mei                    41158  0 
bluetooth             228619  23 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
lp                     17759  0 
parport                46345  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
rtsx_pci_ms            13011  0 
lpc_ich                17061  0 
memstick               16554  1 rtsx_pci_ms
soundcore              12680  1 snd
serio_raw              13215  0 
microcode              22881  0 
dm_multipath           22843  0 
scsi_dh                14843  1 dm_multipath
btrfs                 785967  0 
zlib_deflate           26885  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              12615  1 btrfs
dm_crypt               22820  1 
raid10                 48088  0 
raid456                65844  0 
async_memcpy           12529  1 raid456
async_raid6_recov      12795  1 raid456
async_pq               12912  1 raid456
async_xor              12777  2 async_pq,raid456
async_tx               13291  5 async_pq,raid456,async_xor,async_memcpy,async_raid6_recov
raid6_pq               97812  2 async_pq,async_raid6_recov
raid1                  35240  0 
raid0                  17159  0 
multipath              13145  0 
linear                 12894  0 
dm_raid45              76725  0 
xor                    17116  2 async_xor,dm_raid45
dm_mirror              21946  0 
dm_region_hash         20820  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18529  3 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror,dm_raid45
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         17475  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55399  2 
aes_x86_64             17255  1 aesni_intel
xts                    12885  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13257  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  2 lrw,xts
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20373  4 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
i915                  600396  0 
video                  19390  2 i915,acer_wmi
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
ahci                   25731  2 
drm_kms_helper         49394  1 i915
libahci                31364  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               33355  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
atl1c                  41071  0 
wmi                    19070  1 acer_wmi
drm                   286028  2 i915,drm_kms_helper
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7993996     902544    7091452          0      54568     441044
-/+ buffers/cache:     406932    7587064
Swap:      8200188          0    8200188

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
stop: Unknown instance: 

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
Using last known working set of quirks.

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video: 22: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video: shopt: not found
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
Allocated buffer at 0x11000 (base is 0x0)
ES: 0x1100 EBX: 0x0000

/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:

/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.
Sat Oct 12 11:10:09 CEST 2013: performing suspend
```

Comment: what happens when you hit the power button - does it turn the machine off?

Comment: No. Holding it for 4 seconds is needed to poweroff

Comment: That very likely means that your kernel is broken. Or, more precisely, it doesn't support suspend on your hardware. :(

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94771/linux-mint-15-oliva-cant-wake-from-suspend-hibernate - you've both got the same graphics card. Maybe you should file a bug with Mint. Please check the other question, whether it sounds familiar.

Comment: For me, the Ubuntu suspend/hibernate does not work either, but `hibernate-ram` (tuxonice?) under Gentoo works... never found out why (and never cared, as I just use what works).

Comment: @peterph Does not look like a dupe: I use the Intel card - he uses the nVidia card. My hibernation works - his does not. He can see a mouse when the machine becomes glitchy and freezes - mine is 100% blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed uswsusp and this works:

```
s2ram -f -a 1
```

A big thanks to @frostschutz who made me run `hibernate-ram` which fails with:

```
hibernate-ram:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found.
s2ram: unknown machine, see s2ram(8) and the USuspendRamForce option
hibernate-ram: Aborting.
```

And thus got me to try out `s2ram`.

Visually it suspends exactly the same way (gray screen, then off), but the resume actually works.

Unfortunately it broke hibernation. Oh well, can't win it all.