# Linux Mint 15: Oliva can't wake from suspend/hibernate?

Tags: linux-mint, suspend

As most issues people have had, I can't wake my laptop from suspend or hibernate mode. The computer goes to the lock screen and then freezes up to the point where the mouse won't move, forcing me to do a hard reboot.

If you're interested in my `uname -a` output, here it is:

```
Linux Jason-PC 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the update of `inxi -G`:

```
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M] 
           X.Org: 1.13.3 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau Resolution: 1600x900@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on NVE7 GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.1.4
```

---

The computer now allows me to log in, but Linux becomes all glitchy and unusable. Here are some suspicious lines of `syslog`:

```
Oct 12 12:42:44 Jason-PC mdm[2830]: WARNING: failed to get file info for accountService pic file: Error when getting information for file '/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/jajmo': No such file or directory
Oct 12 12:42:44 Jason-PC mdm[2830]: WARNING: failed to get file info for accountService pic file: Error when getting information for file '/home/jajmo/.face': No such file or directory
Oct 12 12:42:44 Jason-PC mdm[2830]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_file_info_get_attribute_uint64: assertion 'G_IS_FILE_INFO (info)' failed
Oct 12 12:42:44 Jason-PC mdm[2830]: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_file_info_get_attribute_uint64: assertion 'G_IS_FILE_INFO (info)' failed
```

As well as:

```
Oct 12 12:42:37 Jason-PC kernel: [   28.436602] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

Comment: @Jason seems like duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94735/linuxmint15-suspend-to-ram-not-working and actually a problem with the graphics driver - you've both got the same graphics card. Maybe you should file a bug with Mint. Please check the other question.

Answer (score 0):

> The computer goes to the lock screen and then freezes up to the point where the mouse won't move

This implies something in kernel space has gone haywire on wake-up; it's busy looping the processor.   I don't know exactly what the Mint logging configuration is, but check in `/var/log/syslog` (or whatever) after you are forced to reboot.  Scroll back to the last messages from before the reboot, and post a bit of what you find.  If there is nothing obvious, search the log for "hangcheck".